# Simple Shell Script with Arithmetic issue... ** is giving me trouble

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

When I run this script I get this error:

> ./myscript.sh: 16: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "1 ** 1"

When I run this shell script with bash, as in `#! /bin/bash` on the first line, the math works properly; unfortunately I need to use `/bin/sh`.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm on Linux Mint if that matters.

```
#! /bin/sh

x=1
while [ $x -le 10 ]
do
    y=1
    while [ $y -le 10 ]
    do
        echo $(($y ** $x))"   \c"
        y=`expr $y \+ 1`
    done
    echo
    x=`expr $x \+ 1`
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Standard shell arithmetic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) only allows integer arithmetic operations. This doesn't include `**` for exponentiation, which bash has as an extension.

Integer exponentiation is easy enough to implement as a shell function (though you'll run into wraparound soon).

```
pow () {
    set $1 $2 1
    while [ $2 -gt 0 ]; do
      set $1 $(($2-1)) $(($1*$3))
    done
    echo $3
}
```

As an aside, why use `expr` here? Shell arithmetic can do addition.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Another quick question if you don't mind... when writing a bash shell script, what is the bash version of \c... when I put that in it echo's it verbatum instead of the next echo being on the same line.

Comment: @whuff739: `echo -n`. If you want to be portable, use `printf %s 'print\this!exactly+with%no$newline*at;the&end'`.

Comment: You should also check out the `bc` program if you want to stuff other than basic add/multiply/subtract/divide. Example: `echo $(echo '2^3' | bc)` (using `ksh` here)

Comment: @Nitrodist, I'll definitely look into that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're out of luck, as the `**` exponent operator isn't [standard for /bin/sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04). You can use `bc`, though: `echo "$y ^ $x" | bc`.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX shell apparently does not have an exponentiation operator.  You can roll your own:

```
pow() {
    local x y res i
    x=$1
    y=$2
    res=1
    i=1
    while [ $i -le $y ]; do
        res=$(( res * x ))
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
    echo $res
}

x=1
while [ $x -le 10 ]; do
    y=1
    while [ $y -le 10 ]; do
        echo "$(pow $y $x)   \c"
        y=$(( y + 1 ))
    done
    echo
    x=$(( x + 1 ))
done
```